# Did P2SH (BIP 16) get accepted?

Tags: protocol, script, p2sh

Based on this, it seems like it did http://blockchain.info/p2sh but it seems I can't find a definitive answer.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it did, on April 1, 2012.

[removed link to chain of orphaned blocks]

Comment: I'm slightly new to this, how does that show anything?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it did.

```
BIP: 16
Title: Pay to Script Hash
Author: Gavin Andresen <gavinandresen@gmail.com>
Status: Final
Type: Standards Track
Created: 2012-01-03
```

(Final is the stage after being accepted - it means that it's done.)

[(Source.)](https://github.com/bitcoin/bips/blob/master/bip-0016.mediawiki)